# c++ overloaded operator workings

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, operator-overloading

So I wrote this overloaded function for fraction class that has variables num and den.

```
fraction  operator +(fraction & f1, fraction & f2)
{
fraction temp;

temp.num = (f1.num  * f2.den ) + ( f1.den  * f2.num  );
temp.den = (f1.den  * f2.den );

return temp;
}
```

If i use this code as `f1 = f1+f2`, it runs fine.But I want to use it as `f1 = f2+fraction(3,4)`
If I try to use it this way, it shows invalid operands to fraction and fraction.
Can anyone identify this kind of error and why it occurs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The type `fraction&` requires the argument passed must be an **lvalue** (an object whose address
you can take) of type `fraction`. But `fraction(3,4)` is a temporary object, not a **lvalue**, so it can't be passed by reference.

But `const fraction &` need not an lvalue, the temporary variable could be used as the value.

And `f1` and `f2` will not be changed in `operator +`, so you could and should change the parameter declaration to `const &`, which allow the temporary object passed by reference.

```
fraction operator +(const fraction & f1, const fraction & f2)
```

Comment: @Yourfavouritenoob Yes.

Comment: Thanks brother, it worked like a flowing river..Can I ask you why and how it did work?

Answer (score 0):

I usually code a `+=` and then a `+` operator in terms of that.  For example:

```
// member function 
fraction &fraction::operator +=(const fraction &f2)
{
    num = num * f2.den + den * f2.num;
    den *= f2.den;
}

// non-member function
inline fraction operator+(fraction lhs, const fraction& rhs)
{
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

Note that in the second function, `lhs` is not a reference but a copy of the passed `fraction`.  It is a modified version of the copy that is returned by the function.  The non-member function can almost always be written exactly that way.